# how can make all anchor tag (<a>) and image (<img>) fully qualified url in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

how can make all anchor tag and image tag in master and detail pages (asp.net) fully qualified url?

for example: http://example.com/path/file.aspx

**Im using url rewriting and want all my path be fully qualified.**

plz write your code.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far to tackle the problem that didn't work.

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? What are you trying to achieve ? Can you add a sample of what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

use like below

```
<a href="./test.aspx">sample</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of to catch both server control output and standard HTML output is to rewrite the handler output on the fly. [I wrote an HttpModule](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/12/14/urlabsolutifiermodule---convert-urls-in-asp.net-output-to-absolute.aspx) a long time ago that rewrites handler output to fully qualified URLs (<a href="../foo.gif"> to <a href="http://yoursite/images/foo.gif">) for use with FeedBurner. You may be able to take that code and adapt it for your needs.

Note that there may be a performance impact if you take this approach and you will want to ensure that's acceptable.